# Ruby on Rails Rake assets:precompile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new in Rails development and this is my first deployment to Heroku.
When I execute my application (after the deployment) there is an error:

```
2011-09-18T21:05:54+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms
2011-09-18T21:05:54+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-09-18T21:05:54+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled):
```

I googled this and found that I have to precompile my assets, but when trying to do this I found an other error:

```
$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
rake aborted!
No such process - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.11.0/lib/pg_ext.so

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I haven't found any solution for this issue. Is there anyone who faced this an know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Try running it with `--trace` like it says, to get more info. From here the error looks like it's coming from the pg (postgres) gem so it may be a problem with your database connection for the app to start up.

Comment: I run with --trace and found this issue:
 
$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
rake aborted!
?????????????????????????????????????????????????
  (in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jquery-rails-1.0.14/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery-ui.min.js)

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: can you paste the code from your **application.css** or **application.css.[scss|sass]** file please?

Answer (score 38):

I ran into this issue as well and I resolved it by doing the following:

Open up `config/environments/production.rb` and make sure the following option is set to `true`:

```
# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = true
```

Then run:

```
rake assets:precompile --trace RAILS_ENV=production
```

Hope this helps!

~Kevin

Comment: This fixed the same issue for me - THANK YOU!!

Comment: Doesn't help. Setting `config.assets.compile = true` doesn't help to me. I get `TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method` and the rake task doesn't output anything useful.

Comment: # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

Comment: set config.assets.compile = true will have live compilation on production and there is no need to do assets precompile after this.

Answer (score 6):

I got the problem too. But you can

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

in local, and push to heroku with public/assets. It's resolved.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to use the new [Cedar stack](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar). It precompiles assets for you on deploy and overall plays nicer with Rails 3.1, although you will need to configure your app a little bit to work: add some gems to your Gemfile and create a Procfile. But it is still an easier way to go.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error message. My issue was an incorrectly specified font url.

The bulk of this answer shows how I figured it out.

Although I didn't get the path of the asset it was failing on when running

```
RAILS_ENV=production SECRET_KEY_BASE=xxx rake assets:precompile --trace
```

Instead I had this stack trace:

```
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute assets:precompile
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:283:in `sprockets_context'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:124:in `asset_path'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:142:in `asset_url'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:214:in `font_url'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:143:in `_perform'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb:58:in `perform'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/script/tree/list_literal.rb:63:in `block in _perform'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/script/tree/list_literal.rb:63:in `map'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/script/tree/list_literal.rb:63:in `_perform'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb:58:in `perform'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:397:in `visit_prop'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `block in visit'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `visit'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:433:in `block (2 levels) in visit_rule'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:433:in `map'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:433:in `block in visit_rule'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:181:in `with_environment'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:431:in `visit_rule'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `block in visit'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `visit'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:169:in `block in visit_children'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:181:in `with_environment'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:168:in `visit_children'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:188:in `visit_root'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:159:in `visit'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in `visit'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/engine.rb:281:in `render'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:48:in `call'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:185:in `compile'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-rails-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-rails-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `block in execute'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `each'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `execute'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:173:in `invoke'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I modified the gem to spit out the filename

```
subl /Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:124:in
```

like this

```
  def asset_path(path, options = {})
    path = path.value
    puts path
    puts '123'

    path, _, query, fragment = URI.split(path)[5..8]
    puts '126'
    path     = sprockets_context.asset_path(path, options)
    puts '128'
    query    = "?#{query}" if query
    puts '130'
    fragment = "##{fragment}" if fragment
    puts '132'
    Autoload::Sass::Script::String.new("#{path}#{query}#{fragment}", :string)
  end
```

Then when I ran

```
RAILS_ENV=production SECRET_KEY_BASE=xxx rake assets:precompile --trace
```

I got

```
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute assets:precompile
fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf
123
126
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
/Users/smithd98/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:283:in `sprockets_context'
...the rest of the stack trace is the same...
```

Then I found out the issue was a font had been specified like this:

```
.btn-rect {
  font-family: 'OpenSans-Light';
  src:font-url('fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

and should have been like this:

```
.btn-rect {
  font-family: 'OpenSans-Light';
}
```

Comment: Thanks David, I followed your methods of debugging and finally found the problem! For anyone that having trouble to navigate to `sass_processor.rb:124` you can use `gem open sprockets` command, then navigate to the file. Then to save it, use `:w !sudo tee % > /dev/null`

Answer (score 2):

Oh, this is an easy one. Your `PG` gem is breaking your rake task. You can either go the long route to try to fix it, or you can try commenting it out from your gemfile in order to run the precompile.

Answer (score 2):

Yes like Simpleton posted above the PG gem is causing the problem. Imo a better solution would be to move the PG gem inside production in your gemfile and run;
bundle install --without production
Then you should be able to run the rake task without problems

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `config.assets.compile = true` use `config.serve_static_assets = true`

The first option is incorrect, because it tells your server to go back to serving the app/assets folder.

Comment: DEPRECATION WARNING: The configuration option `config.serve_static_assets` has been renamed to `config.serve_static_files` to clarify its role (it merely enables serving everything in the `public` folder and is unrelated to the asset pipeline). The `serve_static_assets` alias will be removed in Rails 5.0. Please migrate your configuration files accordingly.