# Heroku messing up CSS following Hartl's Rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, railstutorial.org

I am having a problem with microposts rendering correctly on heroku, but not on localhost. I am following Hartl's Rails Tutorial guide.

Here is an imgur album showing the issue. The first image is the error(heroku), the second one is correct (localhost).
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EssfS.png

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this would happen. It almost seems like Heroku is ignoring my CSS.

Here is the github repo:
https://github.com/Mciocca/sample_app

Comment: Are the ends of tags being stripped? Doesn't look like a CSS issue.

Comment: How can I check for this? I have noticed using chrome dev tools that my microposts class isn't being used, even though I have set correctly in the html file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like one out of three possible reasons:

1. There's a conflicting stylesheet interfering. Check out app/assets/stylesheets whether there are classes defined twice.
2. Stack. I see you've placed `pg` in production in your gemfile, which is good. Heroku runs on Cedar stack - make sure it is. (`Creating severe-mountain-793... done, **stack is cedar**`)
3. Not assuming anything, but I've been there several times: make sure you've included recent changes to your repo **before** pushing to heroku. `git add .` and `git commit -am "brainfart"`, then `git push heroku master <branch>`.

And congrats on choosing Rails!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I checked to make sure there was nothing conflicting, ensured it was running on cedar, and even made a minor change so I could push it to heroku again. Still no luck =/

Comment: It doesn't look like a problem, but try removing the .gitignore file and do `add .` and commit. (**ONLY DO THIS IF THERE'S NO CONFIDENTIAL INFORMATION IN THE DATABASE OR OTHER IGNORED FILES**)

Comment: I got it to work by enabling precompiling in the config file. Not exactly sure why this caused an issue, but it fixed it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: D'oh, should'ave seen that. Congrats, though, the reason can be read [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline)

Comment: This is also worth a look, it explains how to modify the config for production. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464544/ruby-on-rails-rake-assetsprecompile-error
After you do the rake etc. make sure you push to heroku again.

Answer (score 2):

Run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` to compile the assets incl. the stylesheets into the public hierarchy that is being used by Heroku.

When done:

`git add -A`

`git commit -m "Precompiled assets"` and finally

`git push` and `git push heroku`

For better understanding check out the [Rails Guides on asset pipelines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) and the [Heroku Guides](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline) on assest pipelines.