# Precompiling a .css file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have a `board` controller and I have made a `board.css` file for it.

When I push to heroku I'm getting an error saying `board.css` is not precompiled. Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443536/blueprint-screen-css-isnt-precompiled) I have added

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css *.js )
```

to my `production.rb` file.

This still has not fixed it. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up config/environments/production.rb and make sure the following option is set to true:

```
# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = true
```

Then run:

```
rake assets:precompile --trace RAILS_ENV=production
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464544/ruby-on-rails-rake-assetsprecompile-error)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an assets manifest in your `/assets` folder?

Default manifest file are `/assets/application.js` and `/assets/application.css`.
A manifest file describes all the resources will be precompiled and looks like this:

```
 /*
 * This is a manifest file that'll automatically include all the stylesheets available in this directory
 * and any sub-directories. You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at
 * the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree ./dir
 *= require_tree . 
 */
```

This CSS manifest precompiles itself, all css files in `assets/dir` and `/assets` folders.

**So make sure you have a manifest file and it requires `board.css` with a matching path.**

When you set `config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css *.js )`
 in `production.rb` you are telling Rails that all files in `/assets` folder are manifest file. 
IMHO this is not correct and you have to add only custom manifest files.
Default manifests are already included:

```
# Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
```

About others solutions there's something to say. If you set:

```
  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true
```

It means that you are not forced to have precompiled assets.
The trick works because your app will not raise an error, but you still get an app without precompiled assets and **you'll pay this in page load time**. For this reason this option should always be disabled in production environment.

So when you enable it, calling `rake assets:precompile` will not guarantee you are going to use a precompiled assets. 
Finally remember that Heroku always run `rake assets:precompile` when you deploy your app, so unless you are running your app locally with production environment you don't need to manually precompile your assets.