# Rhomobile doesn't make deploy

Tags: android, compiler-errors, rhomobile

I'm trying to develop an application using RhoMobile, specifically using the Rhostudio 2.0. But every time I try to use the simulator, there is an error:

```
    rake aborted!
No such process
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-3.5.1.13/platform/android/build/android_tools.rb:359:in `kill'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-3.5.1.13/platform/android/build/android_tools.rb:359:in `rescue in load_app_and_run'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-3.5.1.13/platform/android/build/android_tools.rb:347:in `load_app_and_run'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-3.5.1.13/platform/android/build/android.rake:1987:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13/ruby/bin/rake:32:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => run:android => run:android:emulator
Killing adb server
Starting adb server again
Loading package...
CMD: C:/Users/Sebastian/Desktop/android-sdk-windows/platform-tools/adb.exe -e install -r C:/Users/Sebastian/workspace/RhoMobileApplication2/bin/target/android/RhoMobileApplication2-debug.apk 
RET: 1
Error in build application. Build is terminated.
```

I have looked up this thread [Ruby on Rails Rake assets:precompile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464544/ruby-on-rails-rake-assetsprecompile-error), but I still have the problem.

I really hope you could help me,

Thanks

Comment: have you setup JDK, Android SDK and Android NKD path in your Rhodes dev environment? Launching RhoStudio check under rhomobile preferences.

Comment: Yes, also I have configured two virtual devices one with Android 2.3.3 and the otherone with Google API 10.

Comment: What Platform are you running RhoMobile Suite on, and which version?(not the version of RhoStudio, but the rhodes gem version). Have you checked that adb list from a command line return the actual id of the emulator once you are running it?

Comment: @PFM Rhodes 3.5.If I run android list avd, this is the prompt return:
Available Android Virtual Devices:
    Name: AVD1
    Path: \.android\avd\AVD1.avd
  Target: Android 2.3.3 (API level 10)
     ABI: armeabi
    Skin: 800x1280
-
    Name: AVD2
    Path: \.android\avd\AVD2.avd
  Target: Google APIs (Google Inc.) Based on Android 2.3.3 (API level 10)
     ABI: armeabi
    Skin: 800x1280
-
    Name: rhoAndroid233google
    Path: \.android\avd\rhoAndroid233google.avd
  Target: Google APIs (Google Inc.) Based on Android 2.3.3 (API level 10)
     ABI: armeabi
    Skin: WVGA800
  Sdcard: 128M

Comment: @PFM I edit the code and update with the print of the console with --trace. Hope it helps and thanks for your help, but i'm still not able to make a deploy.